# How to capture picture from 2 cameras at the same time?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I know this question has been asked many times before and there has been no solution. But with the new Camera2 API, I think so this is possible to do and I did not find any sample code/solution.

I am trying to capture the images from two cameras on Huawei P20. It has a total of 4 cameras (3 rear, 1 front). I am using one normal camera and one wide angle one. I am able to capture pictures from two cameras using the activity switch i.e. have a button to switch to another activity and then open the camera using a different ID there and then capture the picture and then use the button and shift to main activity and so on.

I have two activities one for wide angle and one for the normal camera. I have two buttons for each activity. One for capturing the picture and one for switching between activities.
So, this is how it looks like on MainActivitiy.java.

```
textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture);
clickBtn = findViewById(R.id.captureBtn);
nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.depthBtn);
clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                takePicture();
            }
        });
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                refreshCamera();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WideCamera.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

The `refreshCamera()` is for releasing the camera resource. This works fine. However, I am unable to show the preview side-by-side. Is there any way I can show the preview side-by-side and capture images without having to switch activities? Is it even possible?

Thanks.